# array subscript is not an integar

Tags: c, arrays

> code for copying string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char from[100]="we are the people",to[100];
    int i,count=0;
    puts(from);

    //copying string
    for(i=0;from[i];i++)
    {
        to[i]=from[i];
    }

    to[i]='\0';
    //printing the new string
    puts[to];


}
```

why compiler show array subscript is not an integar in this statement ?

> puts[to];

but why this does not show error ?

> puts[from];

Comment: Those are both errors. You should write `puts(to);`

Comment: thanx i didnot notice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be 'puts(to);' I think you mixed up with array and function. '[]' is for array and '()' is for function calling.

Answer (score 2):

Chnage

```
puts[to]; to puts(to);
```

puts[to] means you are declaring an array.

- [ ] is used for array size declaration.
- ( ) is used for function calling.